# How to make model.predict in array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 categories of classes Dogs and cats. I've made a list for these categories:

`labels = ["cats", "dogs"]`

I've tried using

```
pred_name = labels[np.argmax(prob)]
```

to show me the label. But I have a problem with model.predict(img).

It only shows me 1. instead of array [0. 1.].

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = cv2.imread('D:cat.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img,(150,150))
img = np.reshape(img,[1,150,150,3])

labels=["cats", "dogs"]

classes = model.predict_classes(img)
print(classes)

prob=model.predict(img)
print("%.2f" % prob)

pred_name = labels[np.argmax(prob)]
print(pred_name)
```

i want my model.predict shows me an array ([0. 1.] or [1. 0.]) instead of just a single number 0 or 1, so I can apply the array into argmax.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`model.predict` should return probabilities of classes. Since you are getting `[1] or [0]` This might be some different problem related with the training part.

Refering this [Returning Probabilities in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47599436/returning-probabilities-in-a-classification-prediction-in-keras), your actual problem may be the normalization in data. Otherwise `predict` should give an output of probabilities. Not the exact classes.